# SolveAlways 'never' completes

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

After allowing *Mathematica* to run on

```
SolveAlways[2 a4 + (3 a3)/(4 Sqrt[x]) + (15 a5 Sqrt[x])/4 + 6 a6 x + 35/4 a7  
x^(3/2) == 1/Sqrt[x] + (3 a2 Sqrt[x])/2 + (3 a3 x)/2 + 3/8 (a2^2 + 4 a4)x^(3/2), {x}]
```

for over an hour I decided that I've done something wrong. Where is my error?

The solution is: $a_2$ arbitrary, $a_3=\frac{4}{3}$, $a_4=0$, $a_5=\frac{2}{5}a_2$, $a_6=\frac{1}{3}$, $a_7 = \frac{3}{70}a_2^2$.

I suspected that the issue is that $a_2$ is unconstrained. So I tried letting ${\tt \{x\}\to \{a_2,x\}}$ after the "${\tt ,}$" but with similar (no) effect.

Comment: My apologies, folks -- I realize this is a ridiculously simple question. But I've read and reread the documentation (which, incidentally, made me realize that if I put $a_2$ in the list of variables then it will not appear in the solution) and am left wondering what I might have missed to perform a check of some simple algebra. Many thanks.

Comment: It's a good question. I can't see your error either. It could be that *Mathematica* simply can't solve this one. (Or maybe it needs some guidance in doing so.)

Comment: Thanks Oleksandr R. You're right, of course, that _Mathematica_ might not be able to solve this. But it seems too simple that it can't be done. If someone else could try running it, I'd certainly upvote. Any suggestions for 'guidance' for _Mathematica_?

Comment: I've tried it in versions 9.0.1 and 10.3 with no success. Both complain that the input is not a polynomial, which may hint at their limitations. Neither has any trouble deciding any one of the parameter values in isolation, but seems to choke when asked for two or more at the same time. I can't really offer you any more than that, I'm afraid.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `SOlveAlways` is getting too  worked up over the "polynomialized" form, whci involves adding new variables and defining relations. See my comment below response from @Dr.Belisarius for one way to bring this closer to a polynomial problem (there will still be denominators, that is, rational functions, but they don't cause trouble here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Losing some generality:

```
SolveAlways[
 Simplify[2 a4 + (3 a3)/(4 Sqrt[x]) + (15 a5 Sqrt[x])/4 + 6 a6 x +  35/4 a7 x^(3/2) == 
          1/Sqrt[x] + (3 a2 Sqrt[x])/2 + (3 a3 x)/2 + 3/8 (a2^2 + 4 a4) x^(3/2) /. 
          x -> y^2, 
          Assumptions -> y > 0], 
 {y}]
```

Of course Assuming `y < 0` yields the same

```
(* {{a5 -> (2 a2)/5, a6 -> 1/3, a7 -> (3 a2^2)/70, a3 -> 4/3, a4 -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: This variant also works: `SolveAlways[(2 a4 + (3 a3)/(4 Sqrt[x]) + (15 a5 Sqrt[x])/4 + 6 a6 x + 
     35/4 a7 x^(3/2) == 
    1/Sqrt[x] + (3 a2 Sqrt[x])/2 + (3 a3 x)/2 + 
     3/8 (a2^2 + 4 a4) x^(3/2) /. Power[x, a_.] -> Power[y, 2 a]), y]`.